# Let $f,g$ continuous and $A$ dense in $D$. Prove is $f(x)=g(x)\forall x\in A$ then $f(x)=g(x)\forall x\in D$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Exercise: Let $f,g$ continuous and $A$ dense in $D$. Prove is $f(x)=g(x)\forall x\in A$ then $f(x)=g(x)\forall x\in D$

I make this, is good my proof?

Let $x_{0}\in D$ and $\left\{ x_{n}\right\} \subset A$ such that

$lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_{n}=x_{0}$.

How $f,g$ are continuous in $D$ then

$f(x_{n})\rightarrow f(x_{0})$ and $g(x_{n})\rightarrow g(x_{0})$,

for hypothesis $f(x_{0})=g(x_{0})\forall x_{0}\in A$, but $A$ is dense in $D$ then $f(x_{0})=g(x_{0})\forall x_{0}\in D$ .

Comment: The proof works.  However, you're using $x_0$ as both a fixed point, and a variable in two quantified statements.  This can easily get confusing.

Comment: Remark that since you chose $\{x_n\}\subset A$, then $f(x_n)=g(x_n)$ and hence have to converge to the same limit.